# mousekeys pointer not visible with mouse removed

Tags: 14.04, mouse, keys

So I tried out mousekeys, and it works, but when I remove the mouse, after I restart, I have no mouse pointer. What can I do to force the mouse pointer to appear even when the mouse is removed? thanks.

Comment: This is ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever my cursour dissappears after a restart I do the following:

I run the command

```
xinput
```

and it gives me a list of input devices:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                           id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Trackball Explorer®             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Mitsumi Electric Apple Optical USB Mouse  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                          id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera                            id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ UVC Camera (046d:08c9)                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ BTC USB Multimedia Keyboard               id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ BTC USB Multimedia Keyboard               id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

My mouse is the `Microsoft Trackball Explorer®` (I do have a second but that isn't relevant here, the `Mitsumi Electric Apple Optical USB Mouse`).

The id is 11, so I run

```
xinput disable 11
```

then

```
xinput enable 11
```

and it normally gets it back.